# properties setting issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I am sending the properties as name, value the name is sent as "name" instead of the argument value of name. Is there a fix for it? Right now I use case to send in right way.

### Working one

```
/**
     * Change properties of the elements
     */
    this.changeProperties = function(type,value) {
        switch(type)
        {
        case "stroke":
            $.DrawEngine.changeProperties({"stroke":value});
            break;
        case "font-family":
            $.DrawEngine.changeProperties({"font-family":value});
            break;
        }
    };
```

### Not working one

```
    this.changeProperties = function(type,value) {
            $.DrawEngine.changeProperties({"stroke":value});
}
```

### Reason

it sends `{type:"red"}` instead of `{"stroke": "red"}`

Comment: How are you calling the not working one?

Comment: I have tried first not working one, as it is not working I am using switch which I want to avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to pass it as

```
this.changeProperties = function(type,value) {
      var obj = {};
      obj[type] = value;
      $.DrawEngine.changeProperties(obj);
}
```

if you had been trying to add the object as `{type:value}`. key is not evaluated as type's actual value instead it becomes the key itself. So you would need to use array notation to insert the value of type being created as the key.

See **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)**